# Can't read html table with pd.read_html

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

on this link: https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIA/2022.html

I want to read this table:
[image]

I use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIA/2022.html"
pd.read_html(url,match="Shooting")
```

But it says: ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Shooting'.

If I try pd.read_html(url,match="Roster") or pd.read_html(url,match="Totals") it searches for these tables.

Answer (score 1):

Its the second table that you want to read. You can simply do:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIA/2022.html"
pd.read_html(url)[1]
```

[image]

Comment: It is not the second table. The name of the table I want to get is "Shooting". This one is "Per Game" table

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that the HTML code commented inside each `div#all_*` are the same with actual scoring tables content. So it looks like the tables somehow generated from the comments using JavaScript after page loads. Obviously it's some kind scraping protection.

Screenshots of what I mean (for Shooting section you want to get):

[image]

[image]

Well, the only solution I see for now is firstly to load the whole HTML of page then modify `req.content` with `replace` function (delete all special HTML comments characters) and finally get the table you want using pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIA/2022.html"
req = requests.get(url)
req = req.text.replace('<!--', '')
# req = req.replace('-->', '') # not necessary in this case

pd.read_html(req, match="Shooting")
```

Since the whole HTML code doesn't contains comments anymore I recommend to get tables by index.

For Shooting - Regular Season tab:

```
pd.read_html(req)[15]
```

and for Shooting - Playoffs tab:

```
pd.read_html(req)[16]
```

Comment: Also note, BeautifulSoup does allow to parse the html comments.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_html()` isn't finding all the table tags. Only 7 are being returned.
Roster, Per Game, Totals, Advanced and 3 others. Shooting is not among them so `pd.read_html(url,match="Shooting")` is going to give you an error.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/MIA/2022.html'
x = pd.read_html(url)
print(len(x)) #7
```